# Is sed with multiple expressions the same as one expression with semi-colons?

Tags: sed

I have a very large file with multiple sed commands to run on it, and I want to avoid out-of-memory errors and save time. Are these all equivalent?

1. `sed -e 'expr1' -e 'expr2' -e 'expr3' file`
2. `sed 'expr1;expr2;expr3' file`
3. `sed expr1 file | sed expr2 | sed expr3`

My guess is that with piping in (3), the stream is processed separately each time, so it would take 3x as long as compared to (2) where it is only processed once). But I am not sure how sed internally processes (1).

Comment: You are right with your guess, and 1 is the same as 2.

Comment: @BenjaminW.maybe write an answer explaining how you know?

Comment: The `-e` option also causes commands to be ended by a newline allowing the commands `i`,`c`,`a` and those ending with a file name such as `w`,`W`,`r` and `R` to be written inline. Another use is as a __package handler__ when used in conjunction with the `-f` option i.e. the fileA contains `s/5/Z/` can be inserted so: `seq 20| sed -e '10,20{' -f fileA -e '}' ` and line 15 becomes `1Z`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, `sed -e 'expr1' -e 'expr2' file` is exactly the same as `sed 'expr1;expr2' file`. Also equivalent are

```
sed 'expr1
expr2' file
```

and storing

```
expr1
expr2
```

(or `expr1;expr2`) in a file, e.g., `sedscr` and calling it with `sed -f sedscr file`, or finally storing

```
/usr/bin/sed -f

expr1
expr2
```

in a file `sedscr` and calling it with `./sedscr file`.

For each input line, sed goes through the complete script and applies all commands to it, then goes to the next input line.

Piping sed calls, on the other hand, has sed go through the whole file each time (and creates a subshell for each call). This might not make a big difference if you do an operation on every line, but imagine a chain of substitutions that depend on each other, like for a file

```
xx
xx
pattern
xx
xx
PATTERN
xx
xx
```

and you want, in a case insensitive manner, end up with uppercase `PATTERN` in parentheses wherever you find it. If you use pipes as in

```
sed 's/pattern/PATTERN/' infile | sed 's/PATTERN/(&)/'
```

you go through the file twice for three operations in total:

```
Initial  1st pass 2nd pass
xx       xx       xx
xx       xx       xx
pattern  PATTERN  (PATTERN)
xx       xx       xx
xx       xx       xx
PATTERN  PATTERN  (PATTERN)
xx       xx       xx
xx       xx       xx
```

but with

```
sed 's/pattern/PATTERN/;s/PATTERN/(&)/' infile
```

you get the same result in just one pass. So, by all means, try and cram everything into a single command.

<sub>GNU sed can do it in a single command: `sed 's/pattern/\U(&)/' infile`.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure what would happen if your first expression consumes multiple lines, but I guess that's a good time to use pipes. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @pfctdayelise Do you have an example of such a first expression? Sed can do almost anything in a single pass with some hold space trickery. (Very often, it would be much easier to use awk, though.)

Comment: Something like
expr1: if '^foo$' is followed by '^bar$', replace foo with baz;
expr2: s/bar/BAR/g
Is a line 'bar' after 'foo' "consumed" by the first exp2 or not?

Comment: @pfctdayelise All executed commands apply to the current pattern space, so the answer is "yes, unless you don't want it to". There are also commands for "branch if there has been a substitution" (`t`), or "branch if pattern space matches something" (`/pattern/b`), you can introduce labels to jump to... check out the [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Examples) in the sed manual, or for something extra crazy, there is [Sokoban in sed](http://aurelio.net/projects/sedsokoban/)...